# Using a parent class but overriding with 'subclass data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am trying to add a base class that has a `from_dict` and `to_dict` method. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return Base(**d)
    def to_dict(self):
        d = dict()
        for k,v in self.__dict__.items():
            if k.startswith('_'): continue # remove fields that start with '_'
            d[k] = v
        return d


class Item(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.age = kwargs.get('age')
        self._nombre = kwargs.get('_nombre')
        self.other = 'hello!'
        super().__init__(**self.__dict__)
```

Here are a few examples of its use:

```
>>> Item().to_dict()
{'name': None, 'age': None, 'other': 'hello!'}

>>> Item.from_dict({'age':12}).to_dict()
{'age': 12} # I want this to also have `name` and `other` keys.
```

Notice when I use the `from_dict`, it doesn't fill in the default values of the subclass. It works when adding the method to `Item`:

```
class Item(Base):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.get('name')
        self.age = kwargs.get('age')
        self._nombre = kwargs.get('_nombre')
        self.other = 'hello!'
        super().__init__(**self.__dict__)
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return Item(**d)
```

But how would I get this to live in the parent `Base` class? And if that's not possible, what is the most 'pythonic' way to do this (a Mixin?)?

Answer (score 0):

You're using to_dict() as a class method, but it isn't one.  Either make it a class method, or call the Item constructor to get an instance and call it's method.

Comment: `to_dict` gives a dict of the instance, how's it a class method?

Comment: On, crud, I missed the (), sorry...  Now, notice that from_dict() invokes the Base constructor, not cls() (does that work? I'd have to experiment), so you don't get an Item, you get a Base, which doesn't do Item's initialization.  Item's (inherited) from_dict method explicitly returns a Base.